# Best way to search in postgres by a group of keyword

Tags: postgresql

right now I have a keyword array like:
['key1', 'key2', 'key3'.......] , the keyword can be number or character.

If I want to search in my table (postgres database), and find out all record contain any of keyword in that array, how can I do that?

For example:
I got a table which has a column called name and a column called description

I need find all record that either name or description contains any keywords in that array.

thanks

Comment: Why yours keys are in an array?

Comment: @Gaston F  it can be any thing in JS(I use Node.js), but it is still a group of keywords

Comment: Then maybe you can use **SELECT field1,....,fieldN FROM table WHERE column_key IN ('key1','key2',.....,'keyN')**. When you say **array**, its a **postgres array** or is the source of your query?

Comment: @GastonF. Yeah, I thought about that, but I need to find out all record which "contain" any of the keys rather than only match the whole. I really have no idea how to do that :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this example will be useful:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
  FIELD_KEY TEXT);

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('this is hello');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('hello');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('this');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('other message');

SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE FIELD_KEY LIKE ANY (array['%this%', '%hel%']);
```

This will return:

```
this is hello
hello
this
```

Here other example:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE FIELD_KEY ~* 'this|HEL';
```

~* is case insensitive, ~  is case sensitive

You can try this example **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f5c4f/4)**.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you tell me how to build an array to store differernt type data. Such as I want to use array[12,'%girl%'], but it dose not work.

Comment: @Kuan: I do not think that can be done, can not create an **array** with diferent data types (in this case, integer and string), but maybe you can CAST or CONVERT the type, for example, **integer** to **text**. So **array[12,'%girl%']** would be **array['%' || 12::TEXT || '%','%girl%']**.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from t
where
    array[name] <@ my_array
    or array[description] <@ my_array
```

Couple the `like` operator with the `any` subquery expression:

```
select *
from t
where name like any (values ('%John%'), ('%Mary%'))
```

Or the array syntax:

```
where name like any (array['%John%', '%Mary%'])
```

Comment: But can you give me some explain about this, I am extremly new to SQL.

Comment: @Kuan `<@` is the _is contained by_ [array operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/functions-array.html).

Comment: thanks for explaining. But if I understand it right, using this I can not do a partial string matching, right?

Comment: Suppose I have a record:    name:"hello" description:"this is hello"  and array is ['hell','hel']. Using that query, I can not find this record, right?

Comment: I just want to find something similar to LIKE but for a group of keywords

Comment: I tried, I use  SELECT name, description from products where name like any (array[12,'%girl%']);  But, postgres told me syntax error at or near "%girl%"

Comment: @Kuan You can't mix types in an array or in a values expression. Make everything a string: `like any (array['12','%girl%'])`